# Multiple Intents on Change of BG Color from one activity to the other @ Android

Tags: android, android-intent

My initial plan was to have a UI preference so the user can pick a bg color from the main activity whenever he/she wants - I got that to work BUT it isn't showing up the right color it's specified to. i.e. When Red button is pressed in Main Activity, it shows up Blue in the next activity instead.

Here is a snippet of the code with only two buttons using multiple intents for demo purposes...

My Main layout:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
        android:onClick="passBG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RED"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
        android:onClick="passBG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLUE"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />
```

Main Activity is working:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view=this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);

 public void passBG(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AudioActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Red", R.color.red);
        intent.putExtra("Blue", R.color.blue);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But something's not right with the second Activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

        int redBG = getIntent().getIntExtra("Red", -1);
        int blueBG = getIntent().getIntExtra("Blue", -1);
        RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_audio);
        rootView.setBackgroundResource(redBG);
        rootView.setBackgroundResource(blueBG);
    }
}
```

I figured out that whichever color in "..."BG is implemented first in

```
  rootView.setBackgroundResource("..."BG)
```

will determine the one that will only pop out. It's something to do with the sequence I figured - AT FIRST ATTEMPT, I tried using the intents on separate methods i.e.

```
public void goRED(View v)
{
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AudioActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Red", R.color.red);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void goBLUE(View v)
{

    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AudioActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Blue", R.color.blue);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

BUT THAT WILL ONLY END UP IN ERROR so I called the buttons on the same method to prevent that problem. So now I'm stuck with a new problem - how do I correctly implement multiple intents to show up the right color BG on the next activity? should I use some if-else statement into it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Let me try to understand, you need to setup the second activity background color based on a user selection in the first activity ?

Comment: Yes! Exactly good sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try this:

Main Activity is working:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    View view;
    private Button redBtn;
    private Button blueBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view=this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray); //This can be achieved by using the `android:background` attribute to your main element on your activity layout

        redBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed); //also, attributes ids on xml layouts shouldnt use uppercase letters, separete words using '_'
        blueBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue);
        redBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onButtonClick(R.color.red);
            }
        });
        blueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onButtonClick(R.color.blue);
            }
        });
    }
    private void onButtonClick(int color){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AudioActivity.class);
        intent.putIntExtra("background",color);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

then, on your second activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

        int color = getIntent().getIntExtra("background", -1);
        if(color != -1){
            RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_audio);
            rootView.setBackgroundResource(color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that did the trick for me! Thank you soooooooo much! It's a very simple concept but I'm still new with Android. I followed your advises regarding id names too! However I had to use `redBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_red); ` 
and `intent.putExtra("background",color);` to make it fully work for me. Why is that the case on my code? Does it differ on Android updates?

Comment: Yup my bad, yo have to cast to (Button) in your case. And the way you set data to your intent is related with the way you get it. If my answer is right please mark it as the Correct Answer! Thanks!

Comment: Was it the tick below the rating buttons? If so, I ticked it to become the Correct Answer. Thanks alot for ur kind help.